# Get Product Custom Option Html In Custom Page

Tags: magento2, custom-options, renderer

I am trying to render custom option in my custom page. I found an example for magento 1 [here](http://inchoo.net/magento/display-html-code-blocks-of-product-options-in-magento/) but it dint work out as in magento 2 **addOptionRenderer** is removed I guess.

I tried this to call in from ajax which will return html

```
$layout = $this->layoutFactory->create();

$block_header = $layout->createBlock('Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options')
->setTemplate('Magento_Catalog::product/view/options.phtml');

$block_links1  = $layout->createBlock('Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\DefaultType','default')->setTemplate('Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/type/default.phtml');
$block_header->setChild('default',$block_links1);

$block_links2  = $layout->createBlock('Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Text','text')->setTemplate('Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/type/text.phtml');
$block_header->setChild('text',$block_links2);

$block_links3  = $layout->createBlock('Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\File','file')->setTemplate('Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/type/file.phtml');
$block_header->setChild('file',$block_links3);

$block_links4  = $layout->createBlock('Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select','select')->setTemplate('Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/type/select.phtml');
$block_header->setChild('select',$block_links4);

$block_links5  = $layout->createBlock('Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Date','date')->setTemplate('Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/type/date.phtml');
$block_header->setChild('date',$block_links5);


echo $block_header->toHtml();
```

The error I am getting is

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function renderAmount()
>   on boolean in
>   /my/magento/path/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/View/Options/AbstractOptions.php
>   on line 143

Comment: Did you found any solution for magento 2 ?

Comment: Can you please help me to solve this? It's very urgent for me.

Answer (score 4):

> I have did code in magento 2.3.0 and its working for me

```
$_product = $this->_objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product);
                $layout = $this->_objectManager->create('\Magento\Framework\View\LayoutFactory');

            $blockOptionData = $layout->createBlock("Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options")->setProduct($_product)
                    ->setTemplate('Magento_Catalog::product/view/options.phtml');

            $block_links1 = $layout->createBlock('Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\DefaultType', 'default')->setTemplate('Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/type/default.phtml');
            $blockOptionData->setChild('default', $block_links1);

            $block_links2 = $layout->createBlock('Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Text', 'text')->setTemplate('Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/type/text.phtml');
            $blockOptionData->setChild('text', $block_links2);

            $block_links3 = $layout->createBlock('Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\File', 'file')->setTemplate('Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/type/file.phtml');
            $blockOptionData->setChild('file', $block_links3);

            $block_links4 = $layout->createBlock('Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select', 'select')->setTemplate('Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/type/select.phtml');
            $blockOptionData->setChild('select', $block_links4);

            $block_links5 = $layout->createBlock('Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Date', 'date')->setTemplate('Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/type/date.phtml');
            $blockOptionData->setChild('date', $block_links5);

            $option_price_renderer_block = $layout
                    ->createBlock(
                            "Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render", "product.price.render.default", [
                        'data' => [
                            'price_render_handle' => 'catalog_product_prices',
                            'use_link_for_as_low_as' => 'true'
                        ]
                            ]
                    )
                    ->setData('area', 'frontend');

            $blockOptionData->setChild('product.price.render.default', $option_price_renderer_block);
            $blockOptionData->setProduct($_product);

            if (!empty($blockOptionData->toHtml()) && strlen($blockOptionData->toHtml()) > 1) {
                return $blockOptionData->toHtml();
            } else {
                return false;
            }
```

Comment: I am getting error in Magento_Catalog::product/view/options.phtml file.
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
        {
            "#product_addtocart_form": {
                "priceOptions": {
                    "optionConfig": <br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getTypeId() on null in /opt/lampp/htdocs/libidexm2/vendor/magento/module-tax/Observer/GetPriceConfigurationObserver.php:50

Can you help in this?

Comment: @ManishMaheshwari, above code is not working in Magento 2.3.4. Can you help?

Comment: The code is working on 2.4.2!